# ansible and postgresql - is there a way to run a .sql file against postgresql database using ansible?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, ansible

This is literally day one for me in evaluating ansible.  I have been asked by the team to show how ansible can be used to solve a specific problem like update 300 databases on 300 different servers... remove 2 rows of data and add 3 new ones.

I found some posts on stackoverflow showing how you can **import** a file using mysql and ansible... but I'm wondering if the same thing can be done with postgres.  i'm looking at the documentation for the ansible postgresql module and it doesn't have import state like mysql.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/postgresql_db_module.html

vs.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_db_module.html

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported by the postgres module but there's nothing stopping you from writing a playbook to move over a dump file and import it into the database.  You could even break up your dump file and template it out.

```
- hosts: db_hosts
  become_user: postgres
  tasks: 
  - copy: src=file.dmp dest=/home/postgres/file.dmp
  - shell: psql dbname < file.dmp
```

I have performed a bulk of my oracle db configuration in this manner

Comment: sweet!  I'll give it a try